# Cover Flow Advice

Tags: iphone, sdk, cover

I need to implement cover flow in our iphone app. Our app need to display images from server. We already have webservice to return list of pictures. Number of pictures will grow over time to 1000s of pictures.

Here I need your help to decide which library is good for my situation without any memory issues. and any experiences you have in similar scenario.

I appreciate any input you can give in my scenario

Here is list of libraries in mind.

1. tapkul
2. OpenFlow
3. FlowCover

Please help deciding which library to use and

Answer (score 1):

I can't help on the issue of which library is best to use, but be aware apps have been rejected in the past for doing including cover-flow like features.

If you really must include cover-flow functionality, I'd recommend you write a little test app with each of the available libraries and see which fits your requirements the best.  You might also try memory profiling the different solutions and see which consumes the least resources.

There probably isn't a "one size fits all" answer to this question, as everyone's requirements will be slightly different.